# Idiomatic pattern for executing javascript generators

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I'm obviously not understanding something about generators...

I have a generator that logs data using `fetch`

```
function* log(logObject) {
  const params = {
    method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(logObject),
  };
  const response = yield fetch('/log', params);
  if (response.ok) {
    const json = response.json();
    return { json };
  }
  return { response };
}
```

I'd like to execute this generator from a regular function

```
function doStuff(stuff) {
  if (hasIssues(stuff)) {
    const logGen = log({ data: { message: 'error log' } });
    return logGen.next().value;

    // but what if i add more yields to `log` in the future?  
    // i'll then need to modify this and every other function that calls `log` to have 2 calls to next()...
    // is there a way to just say, 'do all the things'?

  }
  ...
}
```

How do I make my code flexible enough so that additional `yields` in the generator function don't require me to modify every use of the generator to include additional calls to `next()`?

I guess I could use a `for...of` with an empty block

```
for (let x of log({ data: { message: 'error log' } })) {}
```

but having an empty block loop seems like a code smell...is there a better way?

Comment: Why does your generator `yield` anything if you don't want to use it?

Comment: It looks like you are abusing generators and actually want to use `async`/`await`.

Comment: I do actually use it, just trying to simplify the example...

Comment: @Bergi: can you give an example of the above with async/await?  i hadn't thought of that and would welcome a better pattern

Comment: I don't see where you are using the `fetch(…)` result that you `yield`ed. I suspect the code you posted doesn't even work. Maybe you should show us the full example

Comment: @Bergi: i'm starting to think that i haven't framed a good question...perhaps i should re-write / re-frame...

Comment: Yes, please [edit].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want to use ES8 `async`/`await` to deal with asynchronous promise-using code. Drop generators.

```
async function log(logObject) {
  const params = {
    method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(logObject),
  };
  const response = await fetch('/log', params);
  if (response.ok) {
    const json = await response.json(); // don't forget to wait for the full body
    return { json };
  }
  return { response }; // are you sure you don't want to throw an error?
}

async function doStuff(stuff) { /*
^^^^^ this becomes asynchronous as well */
  if (hasIssues(stuff)) {
    const responseOrJson = await log({ data: { message: 'error log' } });
    …
  }
  …
}
```